# How to define operator in pascal

Tags: pascal, freepascal

In my program I have a need to get percent often in code. For now i have this function to solve it

```
function percent(whole, part: double):double;
 begin
      percent:= whole * part / 100;
 end;
```

I was wondering is there any way I could make new operator so I can write only something like: a:=100%20, and get wanted result. It would also should be able to be used as: c:=b/a; or : c:=c/a;

Comment: Note that the `%` operator is used for `mod` in many languages, and many people would think that your *new* operator means exactly that, i.e. that `a := 100%20;` is equivalent to `a := 100 mod 20;`. In other words, the big problem with self-made operators is that they can easily be misunderstood.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define operators in pascal, but only on record type. It is called **operator overloading** and you can read up [here](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/ref/refch15.html#x207-22900015). What you do is define your own record type data, and then overload standard operators such as **= < > %** etc to do what you want them to do. Here is a simple example:

```
Interface

Type
  TMyFloatType = record
    value: Extended;

    class operator Implicit(n: Extended): TMyFloatType;
    class operator Explicit(n: Extended): TMyFloatType;
    class operator Equal(a, b: TMyFloatType): Boolean;
    class operator GreaterThan(a, b: TMyFloatType): Boolean;
  end;


Implementation


class operator TMyFloatType.Implicit(n: Extended): TMyFloatType;
begin
 result.value := n;
end;

class operator TMyFloatType.Explicit(n: Extended): TMyFloatType;
begin
 result.value := n;
end;

class operator TMyFloatType.Equal(a, b: TMyFloatType): Boolean;
begin
  result := (a.value = b.value);
end;

class operator TMyFloatType.GreaterThan(a, b: TMyFloatType): Boolean;
begin
  result := (a.value > b.value);
end;
```

You can then use that like regular variables:

```
procedure Test;
var
  a, b: TMyFloatType;
Begin
  // first assign some values to a and b
  a := 3.14;
  b := 2.7;      

  if a > b then
  Begin
    // Do something
  End;
End;
```

Operators that you can overload do include math operators too, like `+ - / * mod div` etc.

Now, having said that, I do believe it wouldn't be very convenient to actually implement this to avoid a simple function, but hey, your choice.

Point here is that you can overload an operator to do your bidding. I believe to do a calculation like `percentage :=  a % 20;` you need to overload the Modulus operator.

Comment: Thank you thats what i needed, but now i don't think this all is worth it. Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do this. You can only use the function

Comment: Thank you for fast answer. I asked this because I saw that in Math unit exponent operator is defined as ** so I thought that could be also done by programmer.

Comment: You can implement existing operators for new types (e.g. records, as in the classic TComplex case), but not new operators

Comment: @Marco: I see that, in FPC, beside the ones Delphi knows, the operators :=, >>, << and ** are defined too?

Comment: Like generics, FPC had an operator overloading system before Delphi, as well as C style operators. This is one of the remnants. It might be that >> and << are just aliases for shr/shl

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you @Macro van de Voort

Comment: not true. see below. can it be done ? yes. should it done ? (my opinion) hell no. function is simpler.

Answer (score 0):

I would just use a function.  By the way, your function

function percent(whole, part: double):double;
 begin
      percent:= whole * part / 100;
 end;

is incorrect.  It should be

percent := 100.0 * part / whole;

Comment: I'm sorry but its not. I just badly called them. Part refers to amount in percents and percent refers to value of part percents of whole. But thanks for answer.

Comment: OK, I'm sorry that I misinterpreted it.